# Count the selected Item in CheckboxTreeViewer

Tags: java, jface, rcp

I have an issue when using CheckBoxTreeViewer.
When I checked the child items, I want to show the count number of them in a label.
Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is the Eclipse JFace CheckboxTreeViewer.

Add a check state listener to the viewer using the `addCheckStateListener` method.

In the `checkStateChanged`  method of the listener you can get the number of checked items and update your label.

Use the viewer `getCheckedElements` method of the viewer to get the number of checked elements:

```
Object [] elements = viewer.getCheckedElement();

int cout = elements.length;
```